# How does this property differ from the actual $\varepsilon - \delta$ definition of continuity?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta

I have written the question below verbatim:

Suppose a function $f : \mathbb { R } \rightarrow \mathbb { R }$ satisfies the following property: $$\forall \varepsilon > 0 , \exists \delta > 0 , \forall x , y \in \mathbb { R } , \quad | x - y | < \delta \Rightarrow | f ( x ) - f ( y ) | < \varepsilon$$

(in words: for any positive number $\varepsilon$, there exists a positive number $\delta$ such that for any pair of real numbers $x, y$ the inequality $| x - y | < \delta$ implies 
$ f ( x ) - f ( y ) | < \varepsilon$)

Does it then follow that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb { R  }$?

However, this simply looks to be the $\varepsilon - \delta$ definition of continuity to me. Is there any subtle difference that I am missing here? If so, what would the answer be?

Comment: Note the ordering of the quantifiers. This notion is called uniform continuity.

Comment: This is uniform continuity and is a property defined on the entire set, whereas continuity is usually defined with regards to a single point $c$.

Comment: This defines uniform continuity. Notice that the same $\delta$ applies to all points. Compare this to the definition of continuity where the $x$ is picked first.

Comment: So would giving an example of a uniform continuous function that is not continuous be enough to show that $f$ is not necessarily continuous?